# fabric js json to image from PHP

Tags: php, fabricjs

I know how to make fabric canvas to image as

```
 var canvasImageData = cvsMain.toDataURL({
        format: 'jpeg',
        quality: 0.9
    });
    $('#txtViewJpg').val(canvasImageData);
```

and post this to server.

But, I am generating canvas json in server. and want to convert that json into image.

how can I make image from json in PHP?

Comment: Do you want to output an image in PHP? Or pass your json to your js and then build a canvas in js ?

Comment: I want to generate an Image from json in PHP. I am generating json in my action. all I want to do in server side. Is there any solution?

Comment: Theoretically it is possible to use imagesetpixel() PHP function to draw a pixel. So by converting your JSON into an array, then looping over it and draw a pixel for each iteration you will get a full image.

Comment: I tried this way but it not work for me.http://gadgetsytecnologia.com/0c6f6f888a27e4c04/render-fabric-js-canvas-json-data-image-file-using-imagemagick.html

Comment: Why does it not work? Errors?

Comment: error in loop.. invalid arguments suplied in for loop

Comment: Can you provide the specific code you used in a gist?

Comment: I am trying it once again...

Comment: Getting error 'UnableToOpenBlob' Imagic library error.